# ON DUPLICATE KEY: multi-column unique constraint

Tags: mysql, database

Right now I have:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,2,3,4)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(c),d=VALUES(d)
```

which works if `a` or `b` are `UNIQUE` keys...

But now I want to UPDATE only when another row with the pair (a,b) doesn't exist in the table (otherwise skip insertion).

**Basically `(a,b)` shoud be UNIQUE**, not `(a)` or `(b)`, but both connected.

For example these rows would be valid

```
ID (auto-inc) | a | b |  c  | d
            0 | 5 | 1 | 343 |466
            1 | 5 | 2 | 363 |466
            2 | 5 | 3 | 343 |496
            3 | 7 | 1 | 343 |496
```

Because there's `5,1`, `5,2`, `5.3`, `7.1` etc.

But row #2 here should be considered duplicate of row #1, so row #1 should be updated:

```
ID (auto-inc) | a | b |  c  | d
            0 | 5 | 1 | 343 |466
            1 | 5 | 1 | 363 |466
            2 | 5 | 3 | 343 |496
            3 | 7 | 1 | 343 |496
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

make `UNIQUE KEY` to `(a,b)` not to `b`

```
ALTER TABLE tblname ADD UNIQUE (a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_unique_on_a_and_b ON mytable (a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that if you try to add the ADD UNIQUE(a,b) while there is data in the table, you'll likely get a duplicate key error. Empty the table, add the unique index, and it'll work.